# Library Search Paths randomly delete

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project that was working fine and compiling. When I went to update Google ad SDK to 6.8.0

My library paths started to go crazy, it was saying that Testflight library search path was missing, when I didnt even touch it.
I would re-add the path and nothing, same error, deleting the files, would result in errors with Google SDK and Flurry library search paths going missing.

This however would be fixed by me dragging and dropping the .libs into "Link Binary with Libraries"

And it would work fine until i closed out Xcode, then came back later to continue work, I would have to re-add the libs to "Link Binary with Libraries" every time I open xcode.

Is this just a bug, or am I missing something here.

(Xcode 5.1.1)

This is the error

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/anthonytaylor/Documents/iOS workspace/London-OnTime/London'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LOnTime/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LOnTime'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Folder containing the xcodeproj is London-OnTime, the folder containing the sourcecode is London OnTime

It looks like when xcode launches, it doesnt handle the space correctly in the name.

Comment: I think this issue happen not only deleting library files. It will happen when you delete any files from your project.Is it correct?

Comment: But when i do not delete any files, simply save for the day, and come back the next day, the library file search paths are all screwed up again.

Comment: can you please show the path ?

Comment: @sage444 I added the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way Xcode generated the search paths, I manually entered them in as

```
"$(SRCROOT)/London OnTime/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0"
"$(SRCROOT)/London OnTime/
```

and that fixed it.